# Fail Jenkins build when xUnit tests do not pass

Tags: jenkins, .net-core, xunit.net

I have Jenkins building my C# .NET Core api project. I added some xUnit tests and included a powershell script inside of my Jenkins build with the "dotnet test" command to execute the tests.
That all works well and the tests are run and i can see the output in the Jenkins console. 
The problem is that if i have failing tests nothing happens - jenkins goes merrily along and finished up the build process and reports it as a success.

How can i get it to fail the build?

Is there a response from the 'dotnet test' command?

I know there are xUnit Jenkins plugins but they all seem to revolve around "display the results of xUnit tests". Which is not really what i am after. I want to ACT on the results of the tests, not just see them in fancy html.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You should check for the return code from `dotnet test` command. It returns 0 if all tests were successful and 1 if any of the tests failed. Unfortunately it's not documented but was confirmed in [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest/issues/1624)